# Getting foreignkey id from dropdownlist

Tags: java, jsp

I have two tables students table and department table,
I have Column having student_id, firstname, department_id(foreignkey) for students table.
And department_id, and department_name for the department table.
The department_id in department table is auto increment.

Here it goes the student table is connected to the department and have foreign key of department as department_id. in the dropdownlist from student table student department(department_id(fk)) all department name will be shown and if I choose 1 department name. I want to get the department ID of it and save it in department_id(foreignkey)rather than the department_name it self. because i have an error containing ***"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Math Department""***

This is from my Servlet class

```
    String userdepartment= request.getParameter("department_id");

    String userfirstname = request.getParameter("firstname");

    String userlastname = request.getParameter("lastname");

    studentbean.setDepartment_id(userdepartment);

    studentbean.setFirstname(userfirstname);

    studentbean.setLastname(userlastname);
```

And this is my JSP File

```
    <%
        try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhostdb?user=root&password=root");

Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;

resultset =statement.executeQuery("select * from department") ;

    %>
    <tr>
  <td>Department Name</td>  
         <td><select name="department_id">
            <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
                <option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
          <% } %>
            </select>
    </td></tr>
    <%
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 out.println("Error"+e);
            }
    %>
```

Comment: Could you please fix your code indentation? It's quite hard to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple of helpful tips:

```
resultset =statement.executeQuery("select * from department") ;
```

Never `select *`.  *Always* specify the fields you want in the order you want them to appear.  This is likely to be at the root of your issue

Related to that, you're using the numerically-indexed version of `getString`

```
<option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
```

Don't do that either.  Specify the *name* of the field you want, like this:

```
<option><%= resultset.getString("department_name") %></option>
```

It's also generally considered bad practice to put SQL directly into your JSPs like this.  It's better to do that sort of thing in the servlet and then use request attributes to send objects to the JSP, or *better yet* use a framework.  However, that's just a style critique, and doesn't really impact your result here.

Now, on to your actual problem.  Hopefully, those two tips have already given you a clue why your code isn't working, but let's take a look at the error message.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Math Department"
```

Your program (a part that I think you haven't posted) is trying to decode the value of that dropdown menu as an integer, but the *value* is `"Math Department"`.  Obviously, that's not a number, so it throws an error.  What you need to do is display the department name as the menu label, but have the id as the value.  So, looking at your option tag, you need to do something like this:

```
<option value="<%= resultset.getInt("department_id") %>">
  <%= resultset.getString("department_name") %>
</option>
```

This will show the user the name of the department, but send the id back to the servlet for processing.

Comment: I can get the department_id now but there is a problem. When I'm already adding it to the database using my method, this is the error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
            1""
I already done this. studentbean.setDepartment_id(Integer.parseInt(userdepartment)); but I it has the same error. sorry for my bad english

Comment: See the space character in the `" 1"`?  That's a problem.  `parseInt` is *very* strict about what it allows.  You'll need to `trim()` the string before you can successfully parse it as a number.  If you get stuck, don't be afraid to ask a new question, or search for clues on this site.